# Show $ \sum_1^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2 = \sum_1^{n-1} (x_i -\bar{x}^*)^2+\frac n{n-1}(x_n-\bar{x})^2 $

Tags: statistics

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be a random sample from some population with $n\geq3$ and with at most $n-2$ sample points being equal.
How can one show
$$ \sum_1^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2 = \sum_1^{n-1} (x_i -\bar{x}^*)^2+\frac n{n-1}(x_n-\bar{x})^2, $$
where $ \bar{x}=\frac1n\sum_1^nx_i$ and $ \bar{x}^* = \frac 1{n-1} \sum_1^{n-1} x_i.$
This is a useful identity since it would allow me to have an upper bound on the deviation of $x_i$ from the mean. That is
$$ \max_{1\leq i \leq n} | x_i - \bar{x}| < \frac {n-1} {\sqrt{n}} S, $$ where $ S^2 = \frac 1 {n-1} \sum_1^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2.$

Thank you very much for your help.

Source of the question

A Matrix Formulation on How Deviant an Observation Can Be
Author: Ingram Olkin.
Source: The American Statistician, Vol. 46, No. 3 (Aug., 1992), pp. 205-209 
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2685215

I will add shortly what I've tried so far.

Comment: Your first term on the right hand side is $0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please indicate what you've tried so far, and are possibly having difficulty with. Also, I haven't checked your equation carefully, but I'm fairly certain you are missing a square of the values being added in the first  the term on the right.

Comment: I found the answer in another question. I just didn't find it prior to posting mine. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2442224/512044

Comment: The main result you are trying to prove is [Samuelson's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuelson%27s_inequality). Did you see the original paper [*How Deviant Can You Be?*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2285901?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, Yes, I have seen that article. It's in that article that I have found this useful equality that I am trying to show. The proof of the equality is in this question https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2442224/512044. I used it and I managed to answer my question. Should I write my own answer or leave to somebody else the chance to answer?

Comment: @Fiori_Modena You are welcome to post your own answers and accept them to mark the question as *answered*.